# How to look up or edit existing IBAction?

Tags: ios, xcode

When adding an IBAction by ctrl + drag it is possible to see this menu:

[image]

But how can I access it when IBAction is already created? How can I see or edit the values selected in this menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `IBAction` already existed in `xib` or `storyboard` by click on view / view controller -> on the right menu, select `Show the connections inspector`

[image]

Then at the bottom, check `Received Actions` section:

[image]